# Test queries using SOAP API web service

Tags: web-services, soap

How can I perform test queries using SOAP web service? Which tools or something I should to use? I'm newbie on this topic. I have url, password, login name and I would like to see result of queries in XML format.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the most commonly used tool for testing web services is SOAP UI. This allows you to test just about all aspects of a soap API. From just a basic test request to complete Test Suites

SOAP UI can be found [here](https://www.soapui.org/).